# Parse an array of UUIDs

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I am having problems with parsing an array of UUIDs with jOOQ & PostgreSQL. I have the following query:

```
context
    .select(Tables.T1.IDENTIFIER)
    .select(PostgresDSL.array(context.select(Tables.T2.IDENTIFIER).from(Tables.T2).where(<omitted>)).as("_references"))
    .from(Tables.T1)
    .fetch();
```

This corresponds with the following table structure:

```
t1(identifier uuid primary key)
t2(identifier uuid primary key, t1_identifier uuid foreign key t1(identifier))
```

When doing this query, I get the following exception:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from e472b684-0b04-4799-a3e1-a31711a78182 (class org.postgresql.util.PGobject) to class java.util.UUID
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.fail(Convert.java:1166)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.from(Convert.java:1055)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert0(Convert.java:321)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:313)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:385)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultUUIDBinding.get0(DefaultBinding.java:3805)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultUUIDBinding.get0(DefaultBinding.java:3752)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$AbstractBinding.get(DefaultBinding.java:774)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultArrayBinding.pgGetArray(DefaultBinding.java:1095)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultArrayBinding.get0(DefaultBinding.java:1032)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultArrayBinding.get0(DefaultBinding.java:911)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$AbstractBinding.get(DefaultBinding.java:774)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.setValue(CursorImpl.java:1771)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.operate(CursorImpl.java:1740)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.operate(CursorImpl.java:1705)
    at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:125)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.fetchNext(CursorImpl.java:1669)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.hasNext(CursorImpl.java:1636)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl.fetchNext(CursorImpl.java:408)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl.fetch(CursorImpl.java:394)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl.fetch(CursorImpl.java:301)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:297)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:350)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:323)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:2700)
```

Am I doing something obvious wrong? I believe this worked fine when the identifiers were of type `integer`, but started to fail when I switched to `uuid`.

I am using jOOQ 3.11.9 with PostgreSQL 11.

Comment: Probably a bug. Would you mind reporting it here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new

Comment: @LukasEder Hi Lukas, I create one here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8348 I thank you kindly.

Comment: Is there a workaround possible?

Comment: Probably, if you roll your own data type binding and use plain SQL templating.